# Check if table row contains already inserted string value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

Long story short,

I'm trying to create a table, where you can enter a company name. However you cannot enter a company name which contains a string value of a previous entered company name. Is this possible to do with a check constraint?
For example:

My company "CrazyJello" is inserted. Now the following companies that are being entered to MySQL cannot have the string "Crazy" in them.

```
CREATE table company(
name VARCHAR (100)
CHECK (name != ?????)
```

Comment: Can they have the string `Jello` in them

Comment: And how are you going to identify, programattically, why `Crazy` cannot be used again but `Jello` can

Comment: @RiggsFolly I should've read it through. No you should not be able to write Crazy nor jello. I.E the whole string should be of limits to the next insert

Comment: Umm, so i cannot have `JelloHeaven` because you use `CrazyJello` and I cannot have `ShoppingGoneCrazy` either because you already used `Crazy`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Exactly

Comment: I think you will have to write a trigger for that. Its the only thing I can think of that would allow you to get that granular. It is going to be quite a serious piece of code, so not for the faint hearted. I really cannot think of a real world use for this, so I assume the names you have used are purely for demonstration purposes.

Comment: One of the real difficult bits is going to be getting the code to identify these words within a string. I cannot think of a way to do it, so I hope you have already planned how to decide that `troy` would not make `roy` invalid. Again just an example

Answer (score 0):

No, in sql there is the unique index, but it compares the whole content of the field https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/

Comment: Really only a comment